# GoogleBot Indexing dynamic site content in Google Maps overlay

Tags: google-maps-api-3, googlebot

Dynamic content displayed in Google Maps overlays is not being indexed, apparently because it takes too long. Profiling shows that the vast majority of that time is spent by Google Maps.

Would it be reasonable for the client-side JavaScript to check if the user-agent is GoogleBot, and then ask Google Maps to not load any imagery?

(That would be simpler on our end than not calling Google Maps since the db content to be indexed is in a map overlay, and the site is using the Google Maps API for lat/lng information.)

Is there a way to ask Google Maps API v3 to not load any imagery?

An example of the dynamic content we'd like indexed in the overly here: http://acromaps.com/@37.836161,-122.28133,15z?id=183

(GoogleBot is now executing JavaScript to index some dynamic sites: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html )

I've tried checking (navigator.userAgent.search(/googlebot/i) != -1) and using [{featureType: "all", stylers:[{visibility: "off"}]}] which helps some.